# Same size curved background for all devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

How can I get this background for my app, but I want same curve (same radius) and same size of screen in blue, how can I do this?

[image]

Comment: I think the best way is to make a png image and set it as background resource inside drawable folder

Comment: I think you must use a grey rectangular background and use a blue background in a linear layout with a weight and overlap the grey with the blue!

Answer (score 0):

```
<item android:drawable="?android:colorBackground"/>

<item android:gravity="center"
    android:drawable="?android:colorBackground">
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</shape>
</item>

<item android:bottom="400dp"
    android:left="-120dp"
    android:right="-120dp"
    android:top="-400dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>

</item>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.